# Is there any nfc devices other than mobile phones?

Tags: android

I am developing one application related to Nfc.

I get some information regording nfc through web search.

But i have some questions related to nfc.

1)Is nfc is avilable only in mobiles?

2)If i want to send image through nfc to another nfc device,
i required permistions form other device to send image or not?

3)is it possible to get data from one nfc device to another device automatically?

If any one know this,please send me reply.

Thanks in andvnce.

Answer (score 3):

> 1)Is nfc is avilable only in mobiles?

In terms of Android, at the moment, yes. NFC may become available on tablets in 2012, but right now, the only NFC-enabled devices are phones.

> 2)If i want to send image through nfc to another nfc device, i required permistions form other device to send image or not?

That would be up to whoever writes the image receiver application, just as whoever writes a Web site can decide whether to require authentication or not.

> 3)is it possible to get data from one nfc device to another device automatically?

That would depend upon your definition of "automatically".

Comment: automatically means with out their response.